# Problems with MCP 9.03

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I'm attempting to create a Minecraft mod using the 1.7.2 release of MCP, version 9.03. I may be doing the installation steps wrong, as when I complete the installation, open Eclipse and select the workspace, it gives me 7 errors that I have no idea how to solve. These are the errors:

```
Project 'Client' is missing required library: 'jars/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.0/lwjgl-2.9.0.jar'
Project 'Client' is missing required library: 'jars/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.0/lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar'
Project 'Client' is missing required library: 'jars/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-    platform/2.9.0/lwjgl-platform-2.9.0-natives-windows.jar'
Project 'Server' is missing required library: 'jars/minecraft_server.1.7.2.jar'
Project 'Client' is missing required library: 'jars/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar'
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

If I attempt to run without making any changes, this is the error that is displayed in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Start
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Start
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Please help me out, I'm not using Forge as I plan to be making changes to base class files.

Comment: Just MCP or MCP & Forge?

Answer (score 1):

Open up eclipse and right click on the project "Client", go to build path, configure build path, click on all of the errored files and press remove. Then download the latest LWJGL (http://lwjgl.org/) and extract it to some folder, and import all of the jars. Next, get the natives for all platforms and put them in a new file called LWJGL-Natives.jar and import that as well.

Also, PLEASE do not do a base edit mod! It's bad practice, and will make your mod get little to no use. Try to use either the forge tweak utilities or the official one by mojang: https://github.com/Mojang/LegacyLauncher

Plus, you most likely can do whatever you want to do without ASM or base edits, so please try those before doing base edits.

For project "Server", remove the dependency for the broken resource. It will continue working fine.